# How to remove first element from linq query

Tags: c#, linq

Im trying to consolidate a list of records of in and out times per day to the minimum number of records possible.

What i have done so far, is grouped up the lines into the groups they need to be in, and put the in and out times in a list for each day.

then i want to process the lists and add the first set of in and out lines onto a single line, then process the next entry and either create a new line or fill in the blanks of the previous line.

The bit im stuck with is removing the first item from the linq result after i have processed it.

happy to look at doing it a different way.

here is what i have:

```
       List<LoginRecordLine> condensedLoginRecordLines = new List<LoginRecordLine>();
       List<LoginRecordLine> currentLoginRecordLines = GetLoginRecordsForLoginRecordReport(lowerDate, upperDate, sageDatabaseID, loggedInUserID);

        var groupedLines = from LoginRecordLine line in currentLoginRecordLines
                           group line by new { line.TimesheetID, line.WorkPatternPayRateID } into g
                           select new
                           {
                               Lines = g,
                               TimesheetID = g.Key.TimesheetID,
                               PayRateID = g.Key.WorkPatternPayRateID
                           };

        foreach (var g in groupedLines)
        {
            var monTimes = from line in g.Lines
                           orderby line.MonTimeIn ascending
                           where line.MonTimeSpan != TimeSpan.Zero
                           select new
                           {
                               TimeIn = line.MonTimeIn,
                               TimeOut = line.MonTimeOut,
                               Timesheet = line.Timesheet,
                               PayRate = line.WorkPatternPayRate
                           };

            var tueTimes = //Same as monday

            var wedTimes = //Same as monday

            var thuTimes = //same as monday

            var friTimes = //same as monday

            var satTimes = //same as monday

            var sunTimes = //same as monday


            while (monTimes.Count() != 0 || tueTimes.Count() != 0 || wedTimes.Count() != 0 || thuTimes.Count() != 0 || friTimes.Count() != 0 || satTimes.Count() != 0 || sunTimes.Count() != 0)
            {
                LoginRecordLine condensedLine = new LoginRecordLine();

                if (monTimes.Count() >0)
                {
                    condensedLine.MonTimeIn = monTimes.First().TimeIn;
                    condensedLine.MonTimeOut = monTimes.First().TimeOut;
                    condensedLine.Timesheet = monTimes.First().Timesheet;
                    condensedLine.WorkPatternPayRate = monTimes.First().PayRate;

                    //*************** REVELANT PART *************/
                    //remove first item from monday list
                }

                // tue 

                // wed

                // etc
            }
        }

        return condensedLoginRecordLines;
```

Update - Working code - before performance changes

```
 List<LoginRecordLine> condensedLoginRecordLines = new List<LoginRecordLine>();

                List<LoginRecordLine> currentLoginRecordLines = GetLoginRecordsForLoginRecordReport(lowerDate, upperDate, sageDatabaseID, loggedInUserID);

                var groupedLines = from LoginRecordLine line in currentLoginRecordLines
                                   group line by new { line.TimesheetID, line.WorkPatternPayRateID } into g
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       Lines = g,
                                       TimesheetID = g.Key.TimesheetID,
                                       PayRateID = g.Key.WorkPatternPayRateID
                                   };

                foreach (var g in groupedLines)
                {
                    var monTimes = (from line in g.Lines
                                    orderby line.MonTimeIn ascending
                                    where line.MonTimeSpan != TimeSpan.Zero
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        TimeIn = line.MonTimeIn,
                                        TimeOut = line.MonTimeOut,
                                        Timesheet = line.Timesheet,
                                        PayRate = line.WorkPatternPayRate
                                    }).ToList();

            var tueTimes = //Same as monday

            var wedTimes = //Same as monday

            var thuTimes = //same as monday

            var friTimes = //same as monday

            var satTimes = //same as monday

            var sunTimes = //same as monday

                    while (monTimes.Count != 0 || tueTimes.Count != 0 || wedTimes.Count != 0 || thuTimes.Count != 0 || friTimes.Count != 0 || satTimes.Count != 0 || sunTimes.Count != 0)
                    {
                        LoginRecordLine condensedLine = new LoginRecordLine();

                        if (monTimes.Count >0)
                        {
                            condensedLine.MonTimeIn = monTimes.First().TimeIn;
                            condensedLine.MonTimeOut = monTimes.First().TimeOut;
                            condensedLine.Timesheet = monTimes.First().Timesheet;
                            condensedLine.WorkPatternPayRate = monTimes.First().PayRate;

                            condensedLoginRecordLines.Add(condensedLine);

                            monTimes.RemoveAt(0);
                        }

                        //etc
                    }
                }

                return condensedLoginRecordLines;
```

Comment: You've looked at `Skip`?

Comment: First, you have a serious performance problem in your code: using Count() as you use it is wrong. Replace it with Any(), otherwise you invoke your LINQ queries on each while iteration. Maybe you should even consider materializing the queries using ToList().

Comment: @KirkWoll - no not yet, how will it work if there is nothing in the index to skip?  eg, all lists wont have the same number of entries, there could be 2 on monday but none or one on tuesday

Comment: @galenus - thanks, Ill look at performance once a prototype is working. Any response to my actual question?

Comment: @WraithNath - this is connected, use ToList(), remove the first item.

Comment: @WraithNath - oh, and, of course, in case of ToList() you will get Count property, which is the best from performance point of view.

Comment: Boil down your code to the relevant part.

Comment: Got it working with ToList on the queries that output time in / time out per day. Obviosuly doing ToList is going to more performance as it is, doesnt look like IQueryable has a remove at feature.

Comment: @WraithNath - the problem with your approach is that you use imperative techniques in the last part of your algorithm, while the whole point of LINQ is functional processing of data streams. Exactly for these cases you have the Select() operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the [List.RemoveAt Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx) something like myList.RemoveAt(0) will remove the first item of your list

Comment: Thanks, I think to list might be the way to go, just not sure how they work with anonymous types. ps, the group query is fine, its where im consensing the lines at the bottom of the code that i need to skip.

Comment: @WraithNath Also a good idea to reverse the order and remove from the end instead as all items in the list does not need to be moved then.

Comment: @Magnus - cool, thanks, I think its nearly there. Ill post the working code then change for performance

Comment: @Magnus the List class will surely not move all the items since it is not an array but a list, it will just move the pointer from the first to the second node.

Comment: @RobsonFilhoColodeti It does actually. `List<T>` is implemented with an underlying array. See Remarks section at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx
`RemoveAt` is an O(n) operation, where n is (Count - index)

Answer (score 0):

You should revise your algorithm and maybe data structures.

For anonymous types in queries I would add a DayOfWeek property, so the queries will look like:

```
var monTimes = from line in g.Lines
                       orderby line.MonTimeIn ascending
                       where line.MonTimeSpan != TimeSpan.Zero
                       select new
                       {
                           TimeIn = line.MonTimeIn,
                           TimeOut = line.MonTimeOut,
                           Timesheet = line.Timesheet,
                           PayRate = line.WorkPatternPayRate,
                           WeekDay = DayOfWeek.Monday
                       };
```

Then, the final loop will be replaced by something like:

```
var condensedLoginRecordLines = monTimes
   .Concat(tueTimes)
   .Concat(wedTimes)
   ..//etc
   .Select(data => new CondensedLine { WeekDay = data.WeekDay, /* here all the properties are initialized */ })
   .ToList();
```

And that's all.

If you still prefer to use the MonInTime, TueInTime, etc. properties, move the creation of CondensedLine into a separate function which applies a switch on the WeekDay and initializes the relevant properties only. In this case you should declare a private class instead the anonymous types you currently use in order to pass the information from method to another.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem. In my case, the source data was a CSV file parsed into a string and I wanted to remove the header information before processing. I could have used the approach of casting to a list and removing the first entry, but I discovered that it is possible to add a second parameter to the where query that would give you the row number index. This works with both IQueryable and IEnumerable overloads as well.

```
public static List<string> GetDataLinesFromCSV(string csv)
{
    var csvLines = csv.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var dataLines = csvLines.AsQueryable().Where((x, idx) => idx > 0).ToList();
    return dataLines;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip) function, ex:

```
int[] grades = { 59, 82, 70, 56, 92, 98, 85 };
Console.WriteLine("All grades except the first:");
foreach (int grade in grades.Skip(1))
    Console.WriteLine(grade);
```